# How to get conversation id if we only have send-only permission of user outlook account?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get `conversation id` and `message id` of the messages sent by our app on behalf of the user who only given `send only` permission?

We want to send follow-up mails in the same conversation and there is no way we can do that without `message id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. You need to have `mail.read` in order to find the message `id` and add to the conversation.

Also, it's important to note that the `id` is mutable and can change for any number of reasons (most commonly the mail item being moved to another folder). It is possible to [get immutable identifiers for Outlook resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) but this functionality is still in Preview so, for the time being, it really shouldn't be used in a production environment.